# iphone-How to change the tokenid in URL

Tags: iphone

In login session one Token id was generated, So i need to replace same token id in next screen URL. how we can do that.

Here is clear explanation:
login session token id generated

```
<USER USER_NAME="newadmin01" **TOKEN_ID="0.14002050365183227"** FULL_NAME="newadmin01, newadmin01"/>
```

for next url i need replace login session token id, (0.22341921751959004 replace to "0.14002050365183227)

http://localhost/questionnaire/QuestionnaireList?username=newadmin01&token=0.22341921751959004&levelid=4519
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your URL from

http://localhost/questionnaire/QuestionnaireList?username=newadmin01&token=0.22341921751959004&levelid=4519

to

http://localhost/questionnaire/QuestionnaireList?username=newadmin01&token="0.14002050365183227&levelid=4519

you can use the method below to split the string and then rebuild it.

```
NSArray *string = [stringtoreplace componentsJoinedByString: @"="];
```

That will return an array of strings.

You can then replace the one you want in the array and rebuild it using the stringappend method.

Or easier you can just use stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString to replace whatever you want replacing.

here's the document http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html